# CakePHP App folder location with PHPStorm

Tags: cakephp, phpstorm

I'm using the following locations for **CakePHP** folders:

```
/home/cakephp/lib - for the core files
/home/apps/app - for my application files
/var/www/webroot - for the webroot folder, which is visible by the web server
```

The thing is that when I create a PHPStorm project, my "Project Root" would be `/home/apps/app` but that would mean `webroot` folder is not going to appear inside the project's scope, ergo I would not be able to edit `CSS` or `JS` files located under `webroot/css`, `webroot/js`

How can I solve this?

Comment: 1) Why don't you keep your `webroot` folder inside the actual project? You can then setup automatic deployment so it will copy your files from the project location to the website location (`Settings | Deployment` -- entry of "Local or Mounted folder" type).

Comment: 2) You could (I recommend actually) configure your Apache (or whatever web server you have there) to serve files directly from your project folder so not copy files will be required (have you heard about "virtual hosts" and custom/fake domain names (can be faked via your `hosts` file or local DNS server if you have one) -- works just fine and even better than accessing website via shared `http://localhost/mysite/` URL (compare to `http://mysite.dev/` -- this one is much closer to real-word configuration).

Comment: 3) You can always attach additional external folder to the project -- `Settings | Directories | Add Content Root`

Comment: I'll go with first. Seems the easiest to maintain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few possible options (regardless of the framework used):

1. Keep your `webroot` folder inside the actual project. You can then setup **automatic deployment** so it will copy your files from the project location to the website location (`Settings | Deployment` -- entry of "Local or Mounted folder" type; then check "Options" for automated stuff).
2. You could (I prefer and would recommend this approach) configure your Apache (or whatever web server you have there) to serve files directly from your project folder so no copy files will be required (via virtual host and custom/fake domain name (that can be faked via your `hosts` file or local DNS server if you have one)). This works just fine and even better than accessing website via shared URL (e.g. `http://localhost/mysite/`) -- compare to  `http://mysite.dev/` -- this one is much closer to real-word configuration).
3. Don't do anything from the above -- just attach that folder as Additional Content Root (`Settings | Directories`).